# Reading location from multiple users with unique ID using Swift 4 and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I've been struggling with this one for a two days now. I've searched everywhere and haven't really found an answer that could help me. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords.

Here is the issue.

I have this data in my Firebase Realtime Database

```
-users
 VZUFNaLJ6YN5aqIDaFGmxWKGYNc2
  -location
     -latitude: 123
     -longitude: 123
 RXUFNaLJ6OI7G57DaFGmxWKHG76T
  -location
     -latitude: 321
     -longitude: 321
```

And the output I'm hoping to get is this

---

latitude: 123

longitude: 123

latitude: 321

longitude: 321

---

I really don't have a working code to post here, I was hoping if someone could help me understand what needs to be done. Thank you.

What I have so far is this

```
// Read location from all user
        func globalCoor(){
        ref.child("location").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
           { (snapshot) in
             let locationData = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
            print(locationData)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question (there's a link under it) to show how you initialize `ref`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't have Xcode to see if it works. Remember that if you are loading this into a tableView/collectionView you will have to call `reloadData()`.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class Example: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //Vars
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var locations = [Locations]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        retrieveData()
    }

    func retrieveData() {

        ref.child("users").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                for child in rest.children {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let dict = snap.value as? NSDictionary
                    let latitude = dict!["latitude"] as! String
                    let longitude = dict!["longitude"] as! String

                    let newElement = Locations(withArgs: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                    self.locations.append(newElement)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}


class Locations  {
    var longitude: String
    var latitude: String

    init(withArgs longitude: String, latitude: String) {
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
    }
}
```